# how to match a custom tag name with special characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rspec

I'm trying to add an rspec to test an xml file i am building.  In the actual xml code, i have:

```
<g:shipping_weight>5 lb</g:shipping_weight>
```

I just want to make sure that the value is as i am expecting, but rspec just can't match the tag if it has special characters in it.  a snippet from my spec:

```
context 'verify weight' do
  subject { response.body }
  it { is_expected.to have_css('g:shipping_weight', text: '12.34 lb')}
end
```

`have_selector` and `have_tag` do not match the selector either, so i am relying on using `match` which works, but i'm sure there's a better way?

Comment: The CSS selector `'g:shipping_weight'` is not valid as `:` is used for psuedo-selectors such as `:hover`. I'm not aware of any way to target such custom XML elements with css selectors. You might want to try using find_xpath instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem a few months ago and spent hours Googling before I found the solution. Assuming you are parsing with Nokogiri here, you should able to access the text of this attribute as follows:

```
response.body.at_css("g|shipping_weight").text
```

That's right, you use a pipe, `|`, in place of the colon. I don't think I ever found documentation of this, and I can't now find the example that led me to try this. But it works!

(Note that you will have had to define the `g` namespace at the start of the XML document.)